# How to mix event-programming with SQL transaction?

Tags: events, transactions, modularity

Let me apologize first for that very long question. It is about modularisation of transactional business applications by using events mechanism.

We have a typical business application which allows order placements, dispatching and receiving goods organized in separated modules:

- Order
- Order confirmation
- Despatching
- Reception

Today, we don't have any plugin architecture or things like that. Our modules are just different folders of code within the same code base.

Modules are tightly coupled, 2 examples:

- When an order confirmation is stored, order confirmation modules makes direct calls to order module to update the related order status.
- When a reception is made, reception module make direct calls to despatching module to flag the related despatches as received and also makes direct calls to order module to update the related orders received quantities.

We have much more complex cases and tens (maybe hundreds) of inter-module calls which make the application difficult to maintain and understand. We would like to improve our module model. We want to do it step by step (no full rewrite in a **very** modular and pluggable way for now).

Reading some literature about modular applications and reducing coupling, we believe that event-programming could help us. We think that instead of making direct calls to other modules, each of them should "raise" some events within the application to be caught by others interested in that specific events.

For instance, order confirmation module should raise an "order confirmed" event caught by order module which will update the related order status.

Of course, in our applications, we use SQL transactions to insure data consistency so we ask ourself the following question: should events be raised before or after the transactions are committed?

On one hand, we must have an event raised before the transaction is committed. Indeed, in previous example order status MUST BE updated within the same transaction that stored the order confirmation itself. Also, received quantities must be updated accordingly to receipt storage and despatch flag update.

On the other hand, we have some processing that we would like to trigger only after we are sure the data are committed, for instance: sending an email to notify users for the order newly confirmed.

We conclude that we need to raise 2 events: one before the transaction is committed and the other after the transaction is committed. For instance, we'll have an "order confirm**ing** event" raised within the transaction and an "order confirm**ed** event" raised after transaction commit.

Order module would listen for the first event to update order status and email notification module will listen for the second to send a notification after the order confirmation has been immutably stored and order status updated.

My questions are:

- Are we missing something with that approach?
- Are there some rules / best practice to define events? In our example we have a "order confirmed" event. Should we, or not, have an "order status changed" event further or instead? First approach is more *feature* oriented, second approach is more *data* oriented, which one is best?
- Do we really reduce coupling with that approach or is it just a wrong feeling?
- Should events be used in that 2 forms *ing* and *ed* to support before/after transaction commit?

We already identified some limitations using that design recursively, ie. using nested transactions and raising *ed* events within a module which caught an *ing* event. That problem will be our next problem.

Our application is developed in Java with Spring but I think this discussion is absolutely language and framework agnostic.

Also note that "events" discussed here could be replaced by Observer/Observable pattern, any message queueing system (supporting synchronous messaging for transactional support), etc. That is just an implementation choice, our questions are more at design level now.

Thanks for reading until the end :)

Best Regards